# Can you set an object's DefaultDisplayPropertySet in a PowerShell v2 script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Here is a blog post from Kirk Munro that explains how a script can set the DefaultDisplayPropertySet on its output objects:

[Essential PowerShell: Define default properties for custom objects](http://poshoholic.com/2008/07/05/essential-powershell-define-default-properties-for-custom-objects/)

His technique and example code doesn't appear to work in PowerShell v2. (Note, I have PowerTab and PSCX installed--perhaps those could be interfering.)

Anyone know how to get this to work on PowerShell v2?

---

UPDATE:
Here's the example from the blog post, which isn't working for me (note, I've corrected the single quote characters):

```
$myObject = New-Object PSObject
$myObject | Add-Member NoteProperty Name 'My Object'
$myObject | Add-Member NoteProperty Property1 1
$myObject | Add-Member NoteProperty Property2 2
$myObject | Add-Member NoteProperty Property3 3
$myObject | Add-Member NoteProperty Property4 4
$myObject | Add-Member NoteProperty Property5 5
$myObject

  ## Output:
  # Name      : My Object
  # Property1 : 1
  # Property2 : 2
  # Property3 : 3
  # Property4 : 4
  # Property5 : 5

$defaultProperties = @('Name','Property2','Property4')
$defaultDisplayPropertySet = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSPropertySet('DefaultDisplayPropertySet',[string[]]$defaultProperties)
$PSStandardMembers = [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo[]]@($defaultDisplayPropertySet)
$myObject | Add-Member MemberSet PSStandardMembers $PSStandardMembers
$myObject

  ## Output:
  # Name      : My Object
  # Property1 : 1
  # Property2 : 2
  # Property3 : 3
  # Property4 : 4
  # Property5 : 5
```

The output should not be the same after adding DefaultDisplayPropertySet (i.e., it should only have Name, Property2, and Property4).

Comment: I should also note that I'm running PowerShell v2 on Vista, via the Microsoft Windows Management Framework RC.

http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/08/14/powershell-2-0-for-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008-release-candidate.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you give an example of your non-working code? This should work perfectly in v2, if not, you've found a bug.

UPDATE:

(removed comments about quoting)

I've confirmed with the powershell team that this is indeed a regression (bug).

You can vote on the issue's importance to you here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=487938

Thanks,

-Oisin 
(powershell MVP)

Comment: I had already noticed the invalid single and double quote characters and corrected them. I've added the actual example code to the original question. Does it work for you?

Comment: Correction: it was just single quote characters.

Comment: Just in case others end up here when searching for a way to set the DefaultDisplayPropertySet like I did, this is now fixed. I am running PowerShell V4 and the example code works fine allowing you to specify default display properties.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution I created to work around this issue:

```
function Set-PSObjectDefaultProperties {
param(
      [PSObject]$Object,
      [string[]]$DefaultProperties
     )

$name = $Object.PSObject.TypeNames[0]     

$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?><Types><Type>"

$xml += "<Name>$($name)</Name>"

$xml += "<Members><MemberSet><Name>PSStandardMembers</Name><Members>"

$xml += "<PropertySet><Name>DefaultDisplayPropertySet</Name><ReferencedProperties>"

foreach( $default in $DefaultProperties ) {
    $xml += "<Name>$($default)</Name>"
}

$xml += "</ReferencedProperties></PropertySet></Members></MemberSet></Members>"

$xml += "</Type></Types>"

$file = "$($env:Temp)\$name.ps1xml"

Out-File -FilePath $file -Encoding "UTF8" -InputObject $xml -Force

$typeLoaded = $host.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.Types | where { $_.FileName -eq  $file }

if( $typeLoaded -ne $null ) {
    Write-Verbose "Type Loaded"
    Update-TypeData
}
else {
    Update-TypeData $file
}
```

}

Now you can use the following to create your custom object and set the default properties in PowerShell V2:

```
$myObject = New-Object PSObject
$myObject | Add-Member NoteProperty Name 'My Object'
$myObject | Add-Member NoteProperty Property1 1
$myObject | Add-Member NoteProperty Property2 2
$myObject | Add-Member NoteProperty Property3 3
$myObject | Add-Member NoteProperty Property4 4
$myObject | Add-Member NoteProperty Property5 5
$myObject

  ## Output:
  # Name      : My Object
  # Property1 : 1
  # Property2 : 2
  # Property3 : 3
  # Property4 : 4
  # Property5 : 5

$defaultProperties = @('Name','Property2','Property4')

Set-PSObjectDefaultProperties $myObject $defaultProperties

$myObject

  ## Output:
  #Name            Property2          Property4
  #----            ---------          ---------
  #My Object       2                  4
```

It is also available via PoshCode: [Set-PSObjectDefaultProperties](http://poshcode.org/1523)

Comment: Your sample code worked for me, but alas, this approach did not work in my project (which is PowerShell v3.0).  What you've done is clever -- the function replaces default formatting for the PSCustomObject.  But I have a few objects that derive from this.  I'll probably wind up writing some ps1xml files instead.  +1 for making me learn something.

Comment: Consider a here-string instead of concatenating like that.